# Value of image property (C#)

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I'm trying to solve the problem of changing the value ImageDescription for the Bitmap object. To add a description for the file. Searching the related topics, I have not found a solution.

My code:

```
public Bitmap ImageWithComment(Bitmap image)
{
   string filePath = @"C:\1.jpg";
   var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my comment"); 
   var propItem = image.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault();
   propItem.Type = 2;
   propItem.Id = 40092;
   propItem.Len = data.Length;
   propItem.Value = data;
   image.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
   image.Save(filePath);
   return image;
}
```

But image with new comment dont save in folder(( Please help me

Comment: Is the image source the same file?  That could be the issue.

Comment: Do you get any exception?

Comment: System.ArgumentException: Invalid parameter. in System.Drawing.Image.get_Width () at System.Drawing.Bitmap .. ctor (Image image) in WallpapersSite.Code.ImageActions.SaveImage (Bitmap image)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [MSDN - Property Tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you have to use the proper int value for the `Id`

**Sample**

```
 using (var image = new Bitmap(@"C:\Desert.jpg"))
            {
                string filePath = @"C:\Desertcopy.jpg";
                var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my comment");
                var propItem = image.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault();
                propItem.Type = 2;
                propItem.Id = 0x010E; // <-- Image Description
                propItem.Len = data.Length;
                propItem.Value = data;
                image.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
                image.Save(filePath);
            }
```

using the following number from MSDN

[image: image description code]

after running the code, you can see how it affected the image

**Before**

[image: original]

**After**

[image: after edit]

Comment: I need to change the description of the file, not EXIF. This property number - 40092 (int).

Comment: propItem.Id = 40092; <=== This works and change is what I need

Comment: I need a method to Accepted object type Bitmap, change its properties (description) and the return object type Bitmap

Comment: public Bitmap ImageWithComment(Bitmap image)
{
   var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("my comment"); 
   var propItem = image.PropertyItems.FirstOrDefault();
   propItem.Type = 2;
   propItem.Id = 40092;
   propItem.Len = data.Length;
   propItem.Value = data;
   image.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
   return image;
}

Comment: This function must modify the necessary properties, but this is not happening

Comment: it's all the right methods, and they work. But alas, this is not what I need

Comment: you're not posting the right code, your exception is being thrown from somewhere else..once you post that code we'll be able to help, otherwise i'm not sure what it is that you're asking.

Comment: I send the object Bitmap, but it's not changed and not saved

Answer (score 1):

An ID of 40092 translates to 0x9C9C.  According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.id.aspx), that's not a valid property item id.
According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem.aspx),

> If the image format supports property items but does not support the
>   particular property you are attempting to set, this method ignores the
>   attempt but does not throw an exception.

From the looks of it, you want your ID to be 0x010E.
Also, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534416.aspx) for details on each property item id.

Comment: I need a method to Accepted object type Bitmap, change its properties (description) and the return object type Bitmap