# How to remove special characters from file Metadata c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-upload, special-characters

I am trying to find solution to this from last 2 hours, I have searched a lot on this but didn't found any solution(may be I am searching with wrong keywords), but the problem is I want remove file properties which contain special characters. Please check attached image for what I want to say.

I am using ASP.NET FileUpload control and C# as programming language. I want to make sure that any file uploaded does not contain any special characters in its properties.

[image]

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set and get values in Detail Properties of file? c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17524646/how-to-set-and-get-values-in-detail-properties-of-file-c-sharp)

Comment: Please post your actual code. Then, I think you can use the `System.IO.FileInfo` and `System.IO.FileAttributes` class to get file attributes and then `System.IO.File.SetAttributes()` to change them.

Comment: Comments are stored in the JPG, see how to change metadata :=)

Comment: @Jauch - Thanks for sharing link to existing question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looping through `Image.PropertyItems`?

You can modify the image to remove unwanted details via `GetPropertyItem()` and `SetPropertyItem()`

References:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.propertyitems(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.setpropertyitem(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.getpropertyitem.aspx

Sample here in StackOveflow:
[Value of image property (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231161/value-of-image-property-c)